# Input lag in terminal specific to the last character

Tags: unity, command-line, keyboard, cinnamon

The problem: Typing appears smooth and lag free when typing quickly, but taking a closer look, it seems as though a character is only displayed once either (1) the next character is typed or (2) a second has passed. So basically if I type "display" as fast as I can "displa" will appear quickly, then "y" will appear a second later.

Similarly, if I hold down the backspace, it will speed through the word with no lag, but once it reaches the end (or rather, beginning), it will stop for a second before deleting the final character.

If I were to type a word and wait for each letter to appear before typing the next, I would have to wait a second between each letter.

This is extremely annoying and causing me to make a lot of typos

It happens mostly in the terminal, but it can happen in other places too. It happens in both the gnome terminal as well as terminator. It happens in Gedit, but not chrome

It happens in both cinnamon as well as unity (in their terminals).

Comment: That sounds like a display issue, are there any other display issues, with videos or games or anything? Maybe an updated or different video driver is needed?